# Updating properties of binary Serialized class c# .NET effectively corrupts files

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binaryformatter

I have created a Car class that I am using to store preset serialized versions of Cars with all their various properties and what have you.

I have realised as my program progresses that if I add or remove a property of the Car, every previously serialized file is now unreadable. This as you can imagine, is a problem.

How can I update my class without invalidating all previous files?

-- Clickety

Update : I've added a code sample of what I'm doing
The issue arises if I add/remove a property and try to deserialize a file.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System;


namespace MyCars
{

    [Serializable]
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double TopSpeed { get; set; }

        public Car(string name, double topspeed)
        {
            Name = name;
            TopSpeed = topspeed;
        }
    }


    public static class Serializer
    {
        public static bool LoadCar(string filePath, out Car car)
        {
            Stream TestFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

            try
            {
                car = (Car)serializer.Deserialize(TestFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not deserialize");
                TestFileStream.Close();
                car = null;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static bool SaveCar(string filePath, Car car)
        {
            Stream TestFileStream = File.Create(filePath);
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(TestFileStream, car);
            TestFileStream.Close();

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use binary serialisation then?

Comment: How are you deserialize it?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Use json serialization and ignore properties not present

Comment: I have to use binary serialization for this particular purpose. I cannot use JSON.
I just use the inbuilt [Serializable] attribute.
I will post a code example, it didn't seem necessary as it seemed purely theoretical to me, apologies.

Comment: The only way is to include version number in file name so you can have different versions of the classes to be forward/backward compatible.

Comment: @ClicketyClackety don't use BinaryFormatter. It's not just very fragile, it's also insecure and unfixable. There's a [**very** strong warning in the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0#remarks) explaining that `BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure.` This class is scheduled for removal for years now and wasn't even added in .NET Core 1.0. It was added later just for compatibility purposes with degraded performance

Comment: @ClicketyClackety to see how serious MS is about this [BinaryFormatter serialization methods are obsolete and prohibited in ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete). As in *throw runtime exceptions* obsolete. Use  Protocol Buffers instead

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I hadn't ever noticed those warnings. I guess I could use xml/json and store the bits of data I need to be binary inside of them, whilst keeping text as strings etc.

Comment: @ClicketyClackety protobuf preserves types, even complex ones. You don't have to worry about the actual form either, as it's supported on multiple platforms and most languages.  You can serialize in C# and deserialize in Java, JavaScript, Go, C++, Python. Schema changes are supported as long as you follow some rules. Check [the C# intro for example](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#extending-a-protocol-buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary serialization, as implemented by `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`, is a schema-less binary format. What that means is that if the serializer sees an `int` field, it writes the 4 bytes in the file, same with all the other supported types. It's very fast, but not flexible.

This is different from a serializer that also writes the schema, which would write the 4 bytes, as well as the field name, so later the deserializer can mix and match. As you can imagine, it's slower but much more flexible.

As long as you're sticking with the former, simply don't change the schema. There isn't much else you can do with it.

This is why everyone is going to (and already has) recommend using a schema serializer, like JSON, BSON (binary json), Google's proto-buf, XML, an Sql or Nosql database, anything else really, especially during development when class schemas change often.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware at all. That's very useful to know. I've had a look at the ISerializer interface on MSDN :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-5.0

I assume, even though binary is schema-less, I can put in my own catches and solve for these issues?

Comment: You can take over the automatic process and implement your own, that's correct. One problem you'll run into though is that you don't have the missing information either, you don't know if you're deserializing the version that has the car property or not. And it will only get worse as you have more changes to the type.

Comment: Thanks Blindy, these were all excellent points. And thanks to everyone else, I will most likely change my solution now :)